# How to check if app is already registered with remote notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I tried registering for remote notification in the method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

So when ever the app is lauched, it asks for remote registration everytime. According to me it should not be like this. It should if the app is already registered for it or not.

But i didn't find any method to check the think.

M i thinking right or there is some other way out?

Comment: Please follow the URL it may be helpful: 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672955/remote-notification-token-handling

Comment: does it mean, no need to check if already registered, you just register for them  each and every time app launches???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
+(BOOL)isHaveRegistrationForNotification{

//For ios >= 8.0
if  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];

//For ios < 8
else{ 
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    BOOL deviceEnabled = !(types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone);
    return deviceEnabled;
    }
}
```