# Push Notifications: Associating a device token with a device

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app is currently receiving push notifications that are associated with the previous application user account when this type of situation occurs:

1. Player installs app and registers as "bob"
2. bob's device token registered with web service
3. Player reinstalled app and registers as "phil" (on same device)
4. phil's device token registered with web service

Even though the player is now logged in as "phil" they will continue to receive push notifications for the account associated with "bob" as well as "phil".

If I was using UDID I could ensure that only one device token is registered per device and therefore remove the UDID and device token from the player's old web service account, "bob", thus ensuring only one active account per device. This would happen when the player registers as "phil" and the web server could see that the player has registered a new account with the same UDID and then remove the UDID and device token from any old accounts with that UDID (i.e. the "bob" account). No more push notifications would be sent to the bob account until someone logs into that account again (on the same device, or a new one).

However, this is won't work very well when using CFUDIDCreate since it is likely to change between installs.

How do I ensure that push notifications are only received for the currently logged in user? Or, to put it another way, how do I ensure that my web server stores only one device token per device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the APNS token the key server-side instead of a device specific identifier. When reinstalling the app, you would replace the existing (APNS token, "bob") record by (APNS token, "phil"), thus removing the link between the token and bob's account when reinstalling the app.

As far as I know the APNS token does not change between reinstalls of an app, so this should work. (If it did change between reinstalls in a future version of iOS, this would not be a problem  because the old token would not be valid anymore, so the device would not get notifications sent to bob).

Comment: "As far as I know the APNS token does not change between reinstalls of an app." Is there a definitive answer to this (for current versions of iOS) since @ingaham has suggested the opposite to you.

Comment: Also, I've experienced the device token changing seeminly randomly without any re-installs, so I'd be reluctant to assume it can be used as an identifier at all.

Comment: I'm talking out of experience on iOS versions up to 5, where the token is actually the same for **every** application on the phone (also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-device-token-ever-change-once-created) ). It's true though that the documentation says otherwise, so this may change in the future. As for the token changing randomly without reinstall, I've never experienced that, are you sure nothing else changed between your tests (eg. sandbox/production environment) ?

Comment: It's entirely possible. It was just an ad-hoc observation rather than a well constructed test.

From the link you provided I'm happy to go with your approach on this one, sounds like a very safe bet for what must be typically unusual circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

In case of the app reinstallation the generated device token is the same as before? I think no. You have two different device token registered on your server, one for 'bob' and one other for 'phil', or not?

In this case, the token refers to 'bob' is invalid, an you can filter this using the [APNS Feedback Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3), which is continually updated "with a per-application list of devices for which there were failed-delivery attempts. The devices are identified by device tokens encoded in binary format. Providers should periodically query the feedback service to get the list of device tokens for their applications, each of which is identified by its topic. Then, after verifying that the application hasn’t recently been re-registered on the identified devices, a provider should stop sending notifications to these devices."

Good luck!

Comment: No, you are correct - or at least it can't be guaranteed to be the same. But this is the problem, if it was the same I would just remove it from the old account and add it to the new.

As you say, the feedback service provides a list tokens with failed delivery attempts. However, the push notifications are being delivered successfully do I don't expect to see them in the feedback service.

Comment: Yes,you should leave the app uninstalled for a day for the token be invalid according to this Apple Forum post: https://devforums.apple.com/message/693296#693296
So, it is a hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the iOS 9.x the device token is always distinct and unique on every install of the app. You can save the UUId token to Keychain. The keychain always hold the token even after the reinstall of the app. The keychain documentation from you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html)