# Can device token be recycled?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to maintain a list of device tokens that are sent to my backend, especially on the usage of the Feedback Service.

References:

[Does the APNS device token ever change, once created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-device-token-ever-change-once-created)

[Are push notification tokens unique across all apps for a single device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751481/are-push-notification-tokens-unique-across-all-apps-for-a-single-device)

[Push Notifications: Associating a device token with a device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070102/push-notifications-associating-a-device-token-with-a-device)

From docs:

> The form of this phase of token trust ensures that only APNs generates the token which it will later honor, and it can assure itself that a token handed to it by a device is the same token that it previously provisioned for that particular device—and only for that device.

Does that mean that the token will never be recycled for the particular app? And is sticky for that device even if the user reinstall the app, except when the device has been wiped?

Will I ever be in  a situation that I have not read the Feedback service and the same token has been assigned to another device?

I'm trying to code defensively when there are conflicts, i.e. old token belonging to another user (signed-in user) but the new token belongs to another. Or token has been removed via Feedback Service and recycled from another device?

Answer (score 0):

Not the token is unique, it is as if the serial number of each device, never changes.