# Is Device token for ANPS changed if i download same application after deleting it?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I want to know about changing DeviceToken for same Device.

Here I explain you,

Suppose i download application from AppStore to my device, then app will register device token to server. - lets say it is TOKEN1

Now i delete that app from my Device.And again download that app from AppStore, then the app will again register device token to server. - lets say it is TOKEN2

My question is is TOKEN1 and TOKEN2 are Same?

please clear my doubts.

Thank you,

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-device-token-ever-change-once-created

Comment: It will remain same, even if you create new application with same certificate and on same device, Device Token will be similar for both :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be same as far as device certificate is same for application.

For further information [read apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW12)
It says : `APNs generates a device token using information contained in the unique device certificate`