# Does a iOS Push notification device token change?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

Is there any possibilities for a device token to change after the app is installed and registered for the notification in any kind of scenarios.

Scenarios like:

- App  update
- iOS update
  or in any other random scenario's.

Comment: No, Device token will always be same .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the APNS device token ever change, once created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-apns-device-token-ever-change-once-created)

Answer (score 22):

Previously in document it was like,

> If the user restores backup data to a new device or reinstalls the
>   operating system, the device token changes.

From **new documentation** here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html

> Important: To protect user privacy, do not attempt to use a device
>   token to identify a device.
>
> APNs can issue a new device token for a variety of reasons:
>
> - User installs your app on a new device
> - User restores device from a backup
> - User reinstalls the operating system
> - Other system-defined events
>
> As a result, apps must request the device token at launch time, as described in APNs-to-Device Connection Trust and Device Tokens.

Comment: will didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken get called again after updating the OS? I'm not sure when should I be expecting to get the new updated token. Thanks!

Comment: More importantly, what happens to the user topic subscriptions when the device token changes?  When I detect a token change, do I have to un-subscribe the users original token from all the topics they were subscribed to and then re-register the user for all the same topics using the new token?  Or is this somehow auto-managed in the background - FCM auto removes bad tokens and reassigns new tokens for all the user subscribed topics?

Comment: you should call `registerForRemoteNotifications` on every start of the app. The `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` will be called with an up-to-date token, which you then have to give to your backend somehow.

Answer (score 0):

My app successfully receives Firebase notifications under normal circumstances. However, I've noticed that after terminating the app (i.e., closing it completely) and reopening it, the FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) token undergoes a change. Typically, FCM tokens remain constant unless the user uninstalls the app, but in this instance, the token is unexpectedly altered. Consequently, notifications are not being received as the token has changed.