# Does the registration token refresh whenever the app is launched in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I install app for the first time and it asks for the permission for getting notification, if I press yes then the Device token is generated, but whenever I relaunch the app, I get the error:

```
Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)
```

Can anyone tell whether the device token is generated every time the app is launched?

Comment: check:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-apns-device-token-ever-change-once-created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-apns-device-token-ever-change-once-created) and [http://stackoverflow.com/a/40169657/5575752](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40169657/5575752)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. A (new) token is not generated every time the app is launched. It is generated on initial launch (i.e. first launch after app install). From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token):

> By default, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance on initial startup of your app.

But it may change because of the following scenarios (also from the docs):

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

Comment: No worries. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Today the doc says https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token

> The app is restored on a new device
>
> The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
>
> The user clears app data.

Seems like FCM Token is not generated when we delete the instance ID.