# How to update the old device token with the new device token for Apple Push Notifications (APN)?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

Apple documentation mentions certain scenarios when the device token may change :

APNs can issue a new device token for a variety of reasons like User installs your app on a new device,
User restores device from a backup, User reinstalls the operating system, Other system-defined events.

Lets take one case where the User has reinstalled the IOS, then there is no way to know the old device token.

**What is the way to update the old device token to a new device token ?**
**Is there a way to find that the old device token is invalid ?**

Does it mean that every time a new token is generated , the old device token information becomes stale and there is no way to find out that the old tokens are invalid.

References :  [Does a iOS Push notification device token change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169404/does-a-ios-push-notification-device-token-change)

Comment: Your server that is sending the push notifications should monitor the response from APNS. When it indicates that a token is no longer valid then you should remove it from your database.

Comment: The system sending the Push Notification doesn't get that kind of response from APNs

Comment: Then you will keep sending pushes to invalid tokens forever. The way to find out a token is not valid is to look for the 410 response from the apns service https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html